# Convergence of $\dot{x}(t) = -\alpha(t)x(t) + b\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $x(t)\ge 0$ obey the following differential equation:

$$
\dot{x}(t) = -\alpha(t)x(t) + b\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda t},
$$

where $b>0$, $\lambda>0$, $\alpha(t)\in\mathbb{R}$ is both lower- and upper-bounded, and

$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \alpha(\tau)\ \mathrm{d}\tau = +\infty.
$$

Simulations seem to show that $x(t)\to 0$.

(i) Do you see a formal proof?

(ii) If not, what further hypotheses do we need on $\alpha(t)$ to get $x(t)\to 0$?

**Possible approach**

The Laplace solution reads

$$
x(t) = \mathrm{e}^{-A(t,0)}x(0) + b \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{-A(t,\tau)} e^{-\lambda \tau} \mathrm{d}\tau,
$$

where

$$
A(t,\tau) = \int_\tau^t \alpha(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta.
$$

By hypothesis, $A(t,0)\to+\infty$, so the addend $\mathrm{e}^{-A(t,0)}x(0)$ in $x(t)$ vanishes. Therefore we only need to show that the second addend also vanishes, i.e., that

$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty} \int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{-A(t,\tau)} e^{-\lambda \tau} \mathrm{d}\tau = 0.
$$

We can also observe that $A(t,\tau)=A(t,0)-A(\tau,0)$, which substituted in the limit yields

$$
\lim_{t\to+\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-A(t,0)}\int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{A(\tau,0)-\lambda \tau}\mathrm{d}\tau.$$

Comment: Hint: Can you show that if $g(t)e^{-\lambda t}\to0$ when $t\to\infty$ then $$e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^tg(s)ds\to0\ ?$$

Comment: And now apply this lemma to your setting...

Comment: Well, if $g(t)e^{-\lambda t}\to 0$, it means that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a large enough $T$ such that $|g(t)|e^{-\lambda t}\le \epsilon$ for all $t\ge T$. Therefore,

$$
e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t g(s) ds = e^{-\lambda t} \left( \int_0^T g(s) ds + \int_T^t g(s) ds \right).
$$

Now, the first part vanishes, while for the second we observe that $g(s)\le \epsilon e^{\lambda(s)}$, which means

$$
\int_T^t g(s) ds \le \epsilon \frac{e^{\lambda t}-e^{\lambda T}}{\lambda}.
$$

But this gives me a bound of $\frac{\epsilon}{\lambda}$ for the final limit, not zero. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, $\epsilon$ can be chosen as small as one wants, so maybe that is enough to prove the lemma. I have some trouble seeing how exactly to apply the lemma to my setting though. Could you be more explicit?

Comment: $$\int_0^t \mathrm{e}^{-A(t-\tau)} e^{-\lambda \tau} \mathrm{d}\tau=e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t g(\tau) \mathrm{d}\tau\qquad g(s)=\mathrm{e}^{-A(s)} e^{\lambda s}$$

Comment: I think I cannot write $A(t,\tau)$ as a function of $t-\tau$ only; i need to keep the variables separate, since $A(t,\tau)=\int_\tau^t \alpha(\theta) d\theta$.

Comment: I am referring to the notation in the first version of your question, that is, $A(t)=\int_0^ta$. If you insist on using the two-variables function (which is unnecessary), note that $A(t,\tau)=A(t)-A(\tau)$ and proceed. (For future reference, note how modifying a question without keeping the first version available, when people already started to address it, is a bad idea.)